# Why Thomas Howard thinks Ambassdor is referring "him" to idiot?

Tags: meaning

Thomas Howard and Ambassdor are talking to each other:

> Ambassdor: His Majesty has also heard a rumor.
>
> Thomas Howard: The world is filled with rumors, Monsignor.
>
> Ambassdor: That Your Grace has made contact with Mary of Scots to
>   promote your ambitions. Even that you mean to marry her.
>
> Thomas Howard: **Do you suppose me an idiot**? Your master is the most
>   powerful man in the world. I would not cross him for my life.

What is the offense in Ambassdor's words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambassador seems to be accusing Thomas Howard of plotting to marry "Mary of Scots", a move that is clearly against the "Majesty" Ambassador is referring to. Thomas Howard sees that any move opposing that man (majesty), is foolish, hence by attributing this action to him Ambassador is indirectly calling him an idiot.

Hope this helps :)